# How to survive in the middle of a storm?

Tags: astroneer

No habitat, no rover/truck/spaceship and no cave near. The storm right next to your face, how do you survive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dig out a hole, then close the top. you can do this by holding alt with the terrain tool.

Comment: You don't need to cover it up.  Just be in it.

Answer (score 3):

iDigitalTimes has a "['Astroneer' Beginner's Guide: How To Research, What To Build First And Other Tips](http://www.idigitaltimes.com/astroneer-beginners-guide-how-research-what-build-first-and-other-tips-575098)."  In the section at the bottom titled "Other Tips" they mention this as a potential way to survive a (sand) storm:

> If you see a sandstorm on the horizon, and you’re far away from your base, dig a small shelter into the earth. Make sure there’s an area to the left or right of the door for you to duck into.

I'm sure there are other ways to ensure your survival that will become apparent as the game progresses beyond its current "early release" stage.

Comment: I've tried that, got hit by a flying cube and died lol

Comment: @Alex Ugh, that sucks.  Did you have the shelter dug-out ahead of time?  Or did you really wait until the storm was "right next to your face?"

Comment: I waited untill blocks started flying by my face, I was hoping I could get home...

Answer (score 0):

You should dig a hole in the ground and with a passage either left or right, never deep down (as the rocks can still get you). And make sure you don't stand in the opening of the "dugout".

Comment: This doesn't really add much to the other existing answer, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

1. Dig a deep hole.  Aim at about 45 degree and dig.  Go in and wait.
2. Enter a vehicle (shuttle, rover, etc)
3. Enter habitat
4. Go in an existing cave.
5. Hide inside crashed spacecraft hull.